# Prevent hover on absolutely positioned child to propagate to parent

Tags: css, hover, absolute

I've got an absolutely positioned menu above a parent that has a hover state.

I'm looking for a way to make it so that hovering over the menu won't trigger the parent's hover state.

```css
.row {
  height: 52px;
  background: #F4F3D9;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.row:hover {
  background: black; 
}


.menu {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="menu">
       Hovering me should not make the row black
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `pointer-events:none` of the absolute element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of Javascript to tell the mouseover event on the .menu not to propagate on its parent. Here is an example:

```js
document
  .querySelector('.menu')
  .addEventListener('mouseover', e => { e.stopPropagation() })
```

```css
.row {
  height: 52px;
  background: #F4F3D9;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.row:hover {
  background: black;
}

.menu {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="menu">
      Hovering me should not make the row black
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a pure css solution if one exists.. Also, you accidentally changed the css to be menu:hover instead of row:hover.

Comment: There is no pure css solution for this. Child el is inside parent el, meaning you can't touch child el without touching the parent element. If you don't want to use .js then you have to rearrange your html.